# How do I get the vim bang command to find my functions

Tags: vim

I have functions defined in a file that is sourced by my .bashrc file (shown below). The command is found just fine from the bash command line, and also when I execute a subshell and use the command.  Within a vim session however, the function foo is not found when I execute a bang command. How do I make the foo function visible to the bang command?

```
foofile: 

    printf "%s\n" "here I am in foofile"

    function foo () {
        printf "%s\n" "Here I am in function foo.  Love ya ma!"
    }

    export foo

(in vim) 

:!foo
/bin/bash: foo: command not found

shell returned 127
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call bash function using vim external command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46939026/call-bash-function-using-vim-external-command)

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: if you `export -f foo` in your bashrc, you'll get the functionality you want at the cost of every subshell you make having that function.

`vim` runs its own shell. This shell does not source your `.bashrc`.

You can run `env -i bash --norc --noprofile` to emulate this shell.

This shell still has a minimal `$PATH`. For something to be executed in this shell, it has to be in that path. You should probably use `/usr/local/bin` or `/usr/bin`.

Make a file called `foo` as follows

```
#!/bin/bash
someName() {
    #contents of foo from your bashrc
}
someName #someName here can be foo, and you can just copy your whole function, 
#but I wanted to show that this name doesn't have to relate to the fileName
```

put that file in one of those folders and make it executable (`chmod 744` is a decent bet)

EDIT:

If you don't want to make utility functions have their own files, you can simply source your `.bashrc` as part of your command:

```
:!source ~/.bashrc && foo
```

Second EDIT:

Michail pointed out an alternative, which is to have your `.bashrc` *export* all functions so that they can be used in subshells.

```
foo() {
    ....
}
export -f foo
```

now in vim you can type

```
:!foo
```

and it will work as expected

Comment: Yes,  thanks.  I didn't say so in my question but the command can even go in /User/me/bin (on a Mac, obviously), but I'm trying not to clutter my bin directory with a thousand and one little utility commands.  I have a highly customized my vim environment with lots of scripts.

Comment: `!source ~/.bashrc && foo`?

Comment: Good idea, thx.  (I'll make a shortcut!  nnoremap is my friend!)

Comment: @Leonard, I edited my answer with a better suggestion.